# Overriding the variable in distro.conf config file in custom image recipe yocto

Tags: linux, bash, yocto, bitbake, linux-distro

I want to override a variable file in the `distro.conf` in my `my_image` recipe.

For example by default `distro.conf` variable has defined a variable

```
USER="distroname"
```

Now, I have my custom image recipe called by the name as `my_image.bb`, in that I wanted to override the `USER` variable with some other value

```
USER="imagename"
```

When I bitbake my_image name , in rootfs , I can see it has taken the `USER` value as `distroname` and not the overriding one imagename.

Nevertheless, `bitbake -e my_image` shows the name is overridden properly.

```
 bitbake -e my_image|grep ^USER
 USER="imagename"
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?
Does the variables in distro.conf can not be overridden?

Comment: Can you share the output of `bitbake -e my_image` - just the section that shows the history of the `USER` variable? This should work. Also, how does this variable affect the rootfs - do you write the value into a file?

Comment: yes, actually this USER is linux user. I can see in /etc/passwd file which user is being taken.As mentioned, I am not able to override the USER variable in my_image file.thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do it from a recipe. try putting it in `local.conf` or layer's conf file.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk , thanks. I am not able to change anything in local.conf or in layer.conf . because that default name is being used by other images and workflow that are already set for that.

Comment: Can you explain how the `USER` variable is used to create the entry in `/etc/passwd`? If the recipe code that performs that task is not part of `my_image.bb`, it will not be affected by the variable override. Example code would be really helpful.